# C++ problem: using function

Tags: c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

void imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
{
//Programme
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
image_transport::Subscriber sub = it.subscribe("/camera/image_color", 1, imageCallback);
image_transport::Subscriber sub_depth = it.subscribe("/camera/depth/image", 1, imageCallback);
}
The imageCallback subscriber to the camera; I have two cameras.

The question is how can I use imageCallback in the two differents subscribes, because in that way it doesn't work, I got the two camera's image in the same window = like Toggle images  !!?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/163891/c++-problem:-using-function/) by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on ROS Answers with karma: 751 on 2014-05-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could create a second callback function, or add an additional argument to your existing callback, and pass in additional data using boost::bind.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-05-12**:
OK, this is I think the only way to do that using boost::bind.
Thank you so much.